# OSX - installing Apache/PHP stack trough Homebrew fails

Tags: php, macos, apache, homebrew

I'm stuck. I am trying to install Apache stack on OSX 10.10.3 and i can not get PHP56 to work with Apache. I am getting

> httpd: Syntax error on line 171 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.10/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.10/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/apr-util/libexec/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.10/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so\n  Reason: Incompatible library version: libphp5.so requires version 6.0.0 or later, but libaprutil-1.0.dylib provides version 4.0.0

when running

```
sudo bash -x /usr/sbin/apachectl -k restart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it but I don't know how precisly.

Basically I've reinstalled all PHP packages installed trough brew, and I went back to use Apache 2.4 originally installed on OSX, and not that one from brew.